# Aurora mysql db size decreased post migration

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, storage, amazon-aurora

I've backed up my AWS RDS MySQL database and successfully restored it on Aurora MySQL.

Surprisingly, all 30 tables in both the source and destination databases now have the same number of rows, but some tables in Aurora occupy less storage space compared to RDS. This situation is rather perplexing.

How can I investigate the root cause of this unusual behavior?

RDS (Source)

```
*************************** 198. row ***************************
           Name: watchdog
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Dynamic
           Rows: 785
 Avg_row_length: 37016
    Data_length: 27836416
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 425984
      Data_free: 29360128
 Auto_increment: 31856
    Create_time: 2023-10-25 15:56:36
    Update_time: 2023-11-01 03:12:23
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment: Table that contains logs of all system events.
```

Aurora (Destination)

```
*************************** 198. row ***************************
           Name: watchdog
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Dynamic
           Rows: 785
 Avg_row_length: 4696
    Data_length: 3686400
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 81920
      Data_free: 4194304
 Auto_increment: 31901
    Create_time: NULL
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment: Table that contains logs of all system events.
```

Comment: Did the indexes get recreated? Also, I believe Aurora and RDS use different backend storage engines, so I'm not sure if comparing the table size on each is going to be a worthwhile exercise.

Comment: Indexes were not recreated. Also, engine is InnoDB for both

Comment: Indexes could be the missing piece. Also, I realize they both use InnoDB, but at a lower level Aurora stores things in a fundamentally different manner.